# 22.04 802.11 (wifi) firmware failure

Tags: networking, kernel, iwlwifi, 22.04

I just updated in place (no new harddrive, no new partitions) from 20.04LTS to 22.04LTS. Everything worked except that there is a firmware loading diagnostic (along with a separate failure to compile the VMWare kernel support -- but that may be a VMWare issue, not Ubuntu). Thus, the 802.11 hardware is NOT "seen" by the kernel, etc. (I am using bluetooth to Android phone to our 802.11 network to get to the Internet right now -- not the laptop 802.11). The relevant section of the dmesg log seems to be:

```
[ 30.805966] kernel: iwlwifi 0000:3d:00.0: Failed to load firmware chunk!
[ 30.814167] kernel: iwlwifi 0000:3d:00.0: iwlwifi transaction failed, dumping registers
[ 30.831295] kernel: iwlwifi 0000:3d:00.0: iwlwifi device config registers:
[ 30.841152] kernel: iwlwifi 0000:3d:00.0: 00000000: 08b18086 00100406 0280006b 00000010 d0100004 00000000 00000000 00000000
[ 30.858325] kernel: iwlwifi 0000:3d:00.0: 00000020: 00000000 00000000 00000000 c0708086 00000000 000000c8 00000000 00000100
[ 30.873937] kernel: iwlwifi 0000:3d:00.0: 00000040: 00020010 10008ec0 00130c10 0106ec11 101100ca 00000000 00000000 00000000
[ 30.888621] kernel: iwlwifi 0000:3d:00.0: 00000060: 00000000 00080812 00000405 00000000 00010001 00000000 00000000 00000000
[ 30.903224] kernel: iwlwifi 0000:3d:00.0: 00000080: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[ 30.918557] kernel: iwlwifi 0000:3d:00.0: 000000a0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[ 30.934480] kernel: iwlwifi 0000:3d:00.0: 000000c0: 00000000 00000000 c823d001 0d000000 00814005 fee003f8 00000000 00000000
[ 30.951475] kernel: iwlwifi 0000:3d:00.0: 000000e0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[ 30.969958] kernel: iwlwifi 0000:3d:00.0: 00000100: 14010001 00004000 00000000 00462031 00002000 00002000 0000000e 00000000
[ 30.989997] kernel: iwlwifi 0000:3d:00.0: 00000120: 00000000 00000000 0000000
```

and more. The machine is a HP Zbook G2 that had no issues with Ubuntu 20.04LTS. Any help would be appreciated. Would it work to downgrade the firmware .deb to 20.04LTS or would this be not compatible with the current 22.04LTS production kernel or environment? If downgrading would work, please provide "detailed" instructions (e.g., the apt command invocations to use).

My apologies -- I read "edit" but understood that to be "reply".  In the very limited and controlled Ask Ubuntu system (unlike the Scientific Linux Users List, now effectively defunct with the end of Scientific Linux), only the original posting can accommodate the length of output requested.  Here it is:

```
3d:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 [8086:08b1] (rev 6b)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 7260 [8086:c070]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
(base) ykarant@equality-HP-ZBook-15-G2:~$ sudo dmesg | grep iwl
[sudo] password for ykarant: 
[   24.076333] iwlwifi 0000:3d:00.0: loaded firmware version 17.3216344376.0 7260-17.ucode op_mode iwlmvm
[   24.422354] iwlwifi 0000:3d:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 7260, REV=0x144
[   29.525984] iwlwifi 0000:3d:00.0: Failed to load firmware chunk!
[   29.531924] iwlwifi 0000:3d:00.0: iwlwifi transaction failed, dumping registers
[   29.545841] iwlwifi 0000:3d:00.0: iwlwifi device config registers:
[   29.553920] iwlwifi 0000:3d:00.0: 00000000: 08b18086 00100406 0280006b 00000010 d0100004 00000000 00000000 00000000
[   29.569723] iwlwifi 0000:3d:00.0: 00000020: 00000000 00000000 00000000 c0708086 00000000 000000c8 00000000 00000100
[   29.586499] iwlwifi 0000:3d:00.0: 00000040: 00020010 10008ec0 00130c10 0106ec11 101100ca 00000000 00000000 00000000
[   29.586501] iwlwifi 0000:3d:00.0: 00000060: 00000000 00080812 00000405 00000000 00010001 00000000 00000000 00000000
[   29.586503] iwlwifi 0000:3d:00.0: 00000080: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[   29.586521] iwlwifi 0000:3d:00.0: 000000a0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[   29.586522] iwlwifi 0000:3d:00.0: 000000c0: 00000000 00000000 c823d001 0d000000 00814005 fee003f8 00000000 00000000
[   29.586523] iwlwifi 0000:3d:00.0: 000000e0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[   29.586524] iwlwifi 0000:3d:00.0: 00000100: 14010001 00004000 00000000 00462031 00002000 00002000 0000000e 00000000
[   29.586526] iwlwifi 0000:3d:00.0: 00000120: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[   29.586527] iwlwifi 0000:3d:00.0: 00000140: 14c10003 ffa9cb7b cc3d82ff 15410018 08460846 0001000b 0141cafe 00f01e1f
[   29.586529] iwlwifi 0000:3d:00.0: iwlwifi device memory mapped registers:
[   29.586590] iwlwifi 0000:3d:00.0: 00000000: 00489204 80000040 20000000 08000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[   29.614567] iwlwifi 0000:3d:00.0: 00000020: 00000009 080003c5 00000144 00000000 80000000 803a0000 80008040 00080046
[   29.614589] iwlwifi 0000:3d:00.0: iwlwifi device AER capability structure:
[   29.614631] iwlwifi 0000:3d:00.0: 00000000: 14010001 00004000 00000000 00462031 00002000 00002000 0000000e 00000000
[   29.644851] iwlwifi 0000:3d:00.0: 00000020: 00000000 00000000 00000000
[   29.862240] iwlwifi 0000:3d:00.0: iwlwifi parent port (0000:3c:01.0) config registers:
[   29.887895] iwlwifi 0000:3c:01.0: 00000000: 240412d8 00180407 06040005 00010010 00000000 00000000 003d3d3c 000001f1
[   29.913813] iwlwifi 0000:3c:01.0: 00000020: d010d010 0001fff1 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000040 00000000 0002010a
[   29.939644] iwlwifi 0000:3c:01.0: 00000040: ffc34c01 00000008 00000000 00816405 fee002d8 00000000 00000000 00000000
[   29.966043] iwlwifi 0000:3c:01.0: 00000060: 00000000 0034b009 04001060 04000800 80000000 0a730100 76b50080 21901d27
[   29.992282] iwlwifi 0000:3c:01.0: 00000080: 000f0000 00000000 33083333 00790010 00008000 0000116b 000f0022 00000000
[   30.018668] iwlwifi 0000:3c:01.0: 000000a0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 0000c00d 240412d8 00000000 00000000
[   30.045116] iwlwifi 0000:3c:01.0: 000000c0: 00620010 00008001 00100000 01203c11 10110042 00000000 014803c0 00000000
[   30.071783] iwlwifi 0000:3c:01.0: 000000e0: 00000000 00040800 00000400 00000000 00010042 00000000 00000000 00000000
[   30.098294] iwlwifi 0000:3c:01.0: 00000100: 14010001 00000000 00000000 00062011 00000000 00002000 000000a0 00000000
[   30.124890] iwlwifi 0000:3c:01.0: 00000120: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[   30.152109] iwlwifi 0000:3c:01.0: 00000140: 20c10002 00000801 03000000 00000000 047f0009 80000001 00000000 087f0019
[   30.179021] iwlwifi 0000:3c:01.0: 00000160: 01000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[   30.205729] iwlwifi 0000:3c:01.0: 00000180: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[   30.233243] iwlwifi 0000:3c:01.0: 000001a0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[   30.260663] iwlwifi 0000:3c:01.0: 000001c0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[   30.287747] iwlwifi 0000:3c:01.0: 000001e0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[   30.314751] iwlwifi 0000:3c:01.0: 00000200: 00000000 00000000 00000000
[   30.328522] iwlwifi 0000:3d:00.0: Could not load the [0] uCode section
[   30.342060] iwlwifi 0000:3d:00.0: Failed to start INIT ucode: -110
[   30.355261] iwlwifi 0000:3d:00.0: Collecting data: trigger 16 fired.
[   30.602236] iwlwifi 0000:3d:00.0: Not valid error log pointer 0x00000000 for Init uCode
[   30.628396] iwlwifi 0000:3d:00.0: Fseq Registers:
[   30.641430] iwlwifi 0000:3d:00.0: 0x00000000 | FSEQ_ERROR_CODE
[   30.654712] iwlwifi 0000:3d:00.0: 0x00000000 | FSEQ_TOP_INIT_VERSION
[   30.667690] iwlwifi 0000:3d:00.0: 0x00000000 | FSEQ_CNVIO_INIT_VERSION
[   30.680112] iwlwifi 0000:3d:00.0: 0x00000000 | FSEQ_OTP_VERSION
[   30.692141] iwlwifi 0000:3d:00.0: 0x00000000 | FSEQ_TOP_CONTENT_VERSION
[   30.703537] iwlwifi 0000:3d:00.0: 0x00000000 | FSEQ_ALIVE_TOKEN
[   30.714687] iwlwifi 0000:3d:00.0: 0x00000000 | FSEQ_CNVI_ID
[   30.725524] iwlwifi 0000:3d:00.0: 0x00000000 | FSEQ_CNVR_ID
[   30.735651] iwlwifi 0000:3d:00.0: 0x00000000 | CNVI_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[   30.746014] iwlwifi 0000:3d:00.0: 0x00000000 | CNVR_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[   30.755674] iwlwifi 0000:3d:00.0: 0x00000000 | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_DIG_DCDC_VTRIM
[   30.774437] iwlwifi 0000:3d:00.0: 0x00000000 | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_ACTIVE_VDIG_MIRROR
[   31.759737] iwlwifi 0000:3d:00.0: Failing on timeout while stopping DMA channel 8 [0xa5a5a5a2]
[   31.792310] iwlwifi 0000:3d:00.0: Failed to run INIT ucode: -110
[   31.818068] iwlwifi 0000:3d:00.0: retry init count 0
[   31.825300] iwlwifi 0000:3d:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 7260, REV=0x144
[   36.950039] iwlwifi 0000:3d:00.0: Failed to load firmware chunk!
[   36.956818] iwlwifi 0000:3d:00.0: Could not load the [0] uCode section
[   36.963500] iwlwifi 0000:3d:00.0: Failed to start INIT ucode: -110
[   36.970226] iwlwifi 0000:3d:00.0: Collecting data: trigger 16 fired.
[   37.237985] iwlwifi 0000:3d:00.0: Not valid error log pointer 0x00000000 for Init uCode
[   37.253396] iwlwifi 0000:3d:00.0: Fseq Registers:
[   37.261462] iwlwifi 0000:3d:00.0: 0x00000000 | FSEQ_ERROR_CODE
[   37.269833] iwlwifi 0000:3d:00.0: 0x00000000 | FSEQ_TOP_INIT_VERSION
[   37.278120] iwlwifi 0000:3d:00.0: 0x00000000 | FSEQ_CNVIO_INIT_VERSION
[   37.286548] iwlwifi 0000:3d:00.0: 0x00000000 | FSEQ_OTP_VERSION
[   37.294933] iwlwifi 0000:3d:00.0: 0x00000000 | FSEQ_TOP_CONTENT_VERSION
[   37.303176] iwlwifi 0000:3d:00.0: 0x00000000 | FSEQ_ALIVE_TOKEN
[   37.311300] iwlwifi 0000:3d:00.0: 0x00000000 | FSEQ_CNVI_ID
[   37.319313] iwlwifi 0000:3d:00.0: 0x00000000 | FSEQ_CNVR_ID
[   37.327214] iwlwifi 0000:3d:00.0: 0x00000000 | CNVI_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[   37.334980] iwlwifi 0000:3d:00.0: 0x00000000 | CNVR_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[   37.342643] iwlwifi 0000:3d:00.0: 0x00000000 | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_DIG_DCDC_VTRIM
[   37.357605] iwlwifi 0000:3d:00.0: 0x00000000 | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_ACTIVE_VDIG_MIRROR
[   38.331332] iwlwifi 0000:3d:00.0: Failing on timeout while stopping DMA channel 8 [0xa5a5a5a2]
[   38.366653] iwlwifi 0000:3d:00.0: Failed to run INIT ucode: -110
[   38.393644] iwlwifi 0000:3d:00.0: retry init count 1
[   38.402882] iwlwifi 0000:3d:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 7260, REV=0x144
[   43.606063] iwlwifi 0000:3d:00.0: Failed to load firmware chunk!
[   43.614392] iwlwifi 0000:3d:00.0: Could not load the [0] uCode section
[   43.622605] iwlwifi 0000:3d:00.0: Failed to start INIT ucode: -110
[   43.630862] iwlwifi 0000:3d:00.0: Collecting data: trigger 16 fired.
[   43.902744] iwlwifi 0000:3d:00.0: Not valid error log pointer 0x00000000 for Init uCode
[   43.920547] iwlwifi 0000:3d:00.0: Fseq Registers:
[   43.920557] iwlwifi 0000:3d:00.0: 0x00000000 | FSEQ_ERROR_CODE
[   43.939314] iwlwifi 0000:3d:00.0: 0x00000000 | FSEQ_TOP_INIT_VERSION
[   43.948675] iwlwifi 0000:3d:00.0: 0x00000000 | FSEQ_CNVIO_INIT_VERSION
[   43.957850] iwlwifi 0000:3d:00.0: 0x00000000 | FSEQ_OTP_VERSION
[   43.967043] iwlwifi 0000:3d:00.0: 0x00000000 | FSEQ_TOP_CONTENT_VERSION
[   43.976343] iwlwifi 0000:3d:00.0: 0x00000000 | FSEQ_ALIVE_TOKEN
[   43.985297] iwlwifi 0000:3d:00.0: 0x00000000 | FSEQ_CNVI_ID
[   43.994192] iwlwifi 0000:3d:00.0: 0x00000000 | FSEQ_CNVR_ID
[   44.002871] iwlwifi 0000:3d:00.0: 0x00000000 | CNVI_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[   44.011186] iwlwifi 0000:3d:00.0: 0x00000000 | CNVR_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[   44.019178] iwlwifi 0000:3d:00.0: 0x00000000 | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_DIG_DCDC_VTRIM
[   44.034899] iwlwifi 0000:3d:00.0: 0x00000000 | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_ACTIVE_VDIG_MIRROR
[   45.014365] iwlwifi 0000:3d:00.0: Failing on timeout while stopping DMA channel 8 [0xa5a5a5a2]
[   45.050078] iwlwifi 0000:3d:00.0: Failed to run INIT ucode: -110
[   45.077356] iwlwifi 0000:3d:00.0: retry init count 2
(base) ykarant@equality-HP-ZBook-15-G2:~$ sudo dpkg -s linux-firmware | grep Version
Version: 20220329.git681281e4-0ubuntu1
```

```
$ lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3
3d:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 [8086:08b1] (rev 6b)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 7260 [8086:c070]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
```

```
(base) ykarant@equality-HP-ZBook-15-G2:~$ sudo dmesg | grep iwl
[   24.076333] iwlwifi 0000:3d:00.0: loaded firmware version 17.3216344376.0 7260-17.ucode op_mode iwlmvm

[   29.525984] iwlwifi  Failed to load firmware chunk!
```

```
$ sudo dpkg -s linux-firmware | grep Version
Version: 20220329.git681281e4-0ubuntu1
```

Comment: Is this a dual-boot with Windows? https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi#about_dual-boot_with_windows_and_fast-boot_enabled

Comment: NO -- under no circumstances would I consider a dual-boot unless the two OSs are on separate physical hard/ss drives and that under no circumstances could MS Win access the Linux drive.  I do use Virtual Box, VMWare, and, for the few situations possible, CrossOver (supported licensed for fee WINE).

Comment: The internal Intel 7260 802.11 "card" still does not work under 22.04LTS -- firmware issue.  So as not to transfer through bluetooth to an Android "smart" phone that does connect to our 802.11 access point, I just purchased and installed a USB 802.11 unit that is advertised to and does work with Ubuntu; I did not even have to reboot (but did have to enter the 802.11 security sequence -- NetworkManager had not retained this information).  The USB device is Panda N600 Dual Band (2.4GHz & 5.0GHz) 300Mbps Wireless N USB Adapter w/WPS Button  https://www.amazon.com/dp/B00U2SIS0O

Comment: Until such time that Canonical releases a fix (revised firmware?) for 22.04 LTS to solve this issue, is it feasible to downgrade the firmware .deb file/files to those from 20.04 LTS?  Or, is the 20.40 firmware incompatible with 22.04 LTS?  If it is feasible, which .deb/s should be used and what are the specific commands / syntax to accomplish this?

Comment: I am not convinced it is a bug that Canonical, or the actual author of the driver and firmware, Intel, need to address. My own 22.04 system uses the Intel 7260, loads the same firmware version and works perfectly. Viz: `loaded firmware version 17.3216344376.0 7260-17.ucode op_mode iwlmvm` As well, on AU and Ubuntu Forums, yours is the only case I've seen. I would like to see the size of your firmware file: `ls -al /usr/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-7260-17.ucode` We hope the size is 1049340.

Comment: Note the same size here: https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/tree/ Also note the log shows that the firmware file hasn't changed since 2018; certainly not between 20.04 and 22.04. Can you run a live session of 20.04 where the wireless works correctly?

Comment: ```base) ykarant@equality-HP-ZBook-15-G2:~/Downloads$ ls -al /usr/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-7260-17.ucode
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1049340 Mar 28 23:17 /usr/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-7260-17.ucode``` Any other suggestions?  Note that another user of the same computer model as I am using has the same issue.  It may be an issue in the current Linux kernel and associated kernel  "applications" that has the issue -- in which case, does one downgrade to a previous kernel?  Again, the same hardware was NOT an issue with 20.04LTS and routinely installed the latest nobeta kernels presented by Software Updater.

Comment: I note that the G2 was introduced in 2014. Has your BIOS been updated?

Comment: How does one "update BIOS" from Linux?  The last time I had to do this I had to remove the harddrive, put in the OEM MS Win 7 harddrive (NO LONGER SUPPORTED and I have not updated a harddrive beyond this) and used the HP web site.  Note that 20.04LTS current (and before that, Scientific Linux current) had *NO* issues -- only 22.04LTS has an issue.  Any idea why?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135950/discussion-between-chili555-and-yasha-karant).

Answer (score 2):

In the latest software revision (I installed the latest production Ubuntu 22.04 Linux kernel and kernel related packages as provided by the Software Updater Ubuntu application on 28 June 2022), the issue has been resolved.  During a normal reboot after the kernel "upgrade" the on-board (not USB plug-in) 802.11 chipset is recognized by Ubuntu and the network manager application and seems to function as well as it did under 20.04 LTS.  Thus, the issue evidently was a software defect ("bug") in either the executable source code, the building thereof to a .deb file, or an interpreted configuration file/s -- not a hardware issue with the HP Zbook G2.  Again, the problem seems to have been solved.

Answer (score 1):

https://dev.getsol.us/T3790#68643

add the intel_iommu=off kernel boot parameter in GRUB

Comment: Could you add more details to your answer?  As such, it relies too much on the link you refer to and that could disappear.  Add to which file to add what you suggest and how.  Leave the link as reference.

Answer (score 1):

The [comment by chili555](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1405123/22-04-802-11-wifi-firmware-failure#comment2440807_1405123) helped with iwlwifi on a Thinkpad P15 that had been updated to Ubuntu 22.04 and linux-firmware 20220329.git681281e4-0ubuntu3.2. The solution was to hold down the power button for 5 seconds to power cycle the laptop. Soft reboots would consistently result in wifi failure and the following dmesg entries:

```
$ sudo dmesg | grep iwl
[   18.322050] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[   18.343343] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: api flags index 2 larger than supported by driver
[   18.343360] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: TLV_FW_FSEQ_VERSION: FSEQ Version: 0.63.2.2
[   18.343624] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: loaded firmware version 66.f1c864e0.0 ty-a0-gf-a0-66.ucode op_mode iwlmvm
[   18.462210] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6 AX210 160MHz, REV=0x420
[   19.475649] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: SecBoot CPU1 Status: 0x75aa, CPU2 Status: 0xb03
[   19.475669] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: UMAC PC: 0x8047f600
[   19.475679] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: LMAC PC: 0x0
[   19.475681] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: WRT: Collecting data: ini trigger 13 fired (delay=0ms).
[   19.475789] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: Loaded firmware version: 66.f1c864e0.0 ty-a0-gf-a0-66.ucode
[   19.475790] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | ADVANCED_SYSASSERT
[   19.475791] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | trm_hw_status0
[   19.475792] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | trm_hw_status1
[   19.475792] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | branchlink2
[   19.475793] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | interruptlink1
[   19.475793] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | interruptlink2
[   19.475794] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | data1
[   19.475795] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | data2
[   19.475795] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | data3
[   19.475796] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | beacon time
[   19.475796] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | tsf low
[   19.475797] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | tsf hi
[   19.475797] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | time gp1
[   19.475798] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | time gp2
[   19.475798] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | uCode revision type
[   19.475799] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | uCode version major
[   19.475800] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | uCode version minor
[   19.475800] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | hw version
[   19.475801] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | board version
[   19.475801] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | hcmd
[   19.475802] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr0
[   19.475803] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr1
[   19.475803] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr2
[   19.475804] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr3
[   19.475804] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr4
[   19.475805] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | last cmd Id
[   19.475805] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | wait_event
[   19.475806] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | l2p_control
[   19.475807] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | l2p_duration
[   19.475807] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | l2p_mhvalid
[   19.475808] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | l2p_addr_match
[   19.475808] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | lmpm_pmg_sel
[   19.475809] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | timestamp
[   19.475809] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | flow_handler
[   19.475888] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
[   19.475889] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: Transport status: 0x00000042, valid: 7
[   19.475890] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x201013F2 | ADVANCED_SYSASSERT
[   19.475890] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | umac branchlink1
[   19.475891] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x8045DFC6 | umac branchlink2
[   19.475892] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | umac interruptlink1
[   19.475892] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | umac interruptlink2
[   19.475893] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x0000000C | umac data1
[   19.475894] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00040000 | umac data2
[   19.475894] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0xDEADBEEF | umac data3
[   19.475895] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000042 | umac major
[   19.475895] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0xF1C864E0 | umac minor
[   19.475896] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x0001209A | frame pointer
[   19.475897] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0xC0887F34 | stack pointer
[   19.475897] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | last host cmd
[   19.475898] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr status reg
[   19.475947] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: IML/ROM dump:
[   19.475948] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000B03 | IML/ROM error/state
[   19.475959] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x000075AA | IML/ROM data1
[   19.475975] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000080 | IML/ROM WFPM_AUTH_KEY_0
[   19.475981] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: Fseq Registers:
[   19.475985] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x60000100 | FSEQ_ERROR_CODE
[   19.475991] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00440005 | FSEQ_TOP_INIT_VERSION
[   19.475999] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00080009 | FSEQ_CNVIO_INIT_VERSION
[   19.476006] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x0000A652 | FSEQ_OTP_VERSION
[   19.476018] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000002 | FSEQ_TOP_CONTENT_VERSION
[   19.476029] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x4552414E | FSEQ_ALIVE_TOKEN
[   19.476036] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00400410 | FSEQ_CNVI_ID
[   19.476039] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00400410 | FSEQ_CNVR_ID
[   19.476042] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00400410 | CNVI_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[   19.476047] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00400410 | CNVR_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[   19.476053] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00009061 | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_DIG_DCDC_VTRIM
[   19.476058] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000061 | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_ACTIVE_VDIG_MIRROR
[   19.476061] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: Failed to start RT ucode: -110
[   19.476062] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: WRT: Collecting data: ini trigger 13 fired (delay=0ms).
[   21.417382] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: Failed to run INIT ucode: -110
[   21.430118] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: retry init count 0
[   21.435987] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6 AX210 160MHz, REV=0x420
[   22.451641] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: SecBoot CPU1 Status: 0x75a2, CPU2 Status: 0xb03
[   22.451665] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: UMAC PC: 0x8047f600
[   22.451676] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: LMAC PC: 0x0
[   22.451678] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: WRT: Collecting data: ini trigger 13 fired (delay=0ms).
[   22.451787] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: Loaded firmware version: 66.f1c864e0.0 ty-a0-gf-a0-66.ucode
[   22.451788] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | ADVANCED_SYSASSERT
[   22.451790] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | trm_hw_status0
[   22.451791] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | trm_hw_status1
[   22.451791] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | branchlink2
[   22.451792] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | interruptlink1
[   22.451793] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | interruptlink2
[   22.451794] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | data1
[   22.451795] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | data2
[   22.451796] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | data3
[   22.451796] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | beacon time
[   22.451797] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | tsf low
[   22.451798] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | tsf hi
[   22.451799] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | time gp1
[   22.451800] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | time gp2
[   22.451801] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | uCode revision type
[   22.451802] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | uCode version major
[   22.451802] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | uCode version minor
[   22.451803] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | hw version
[   22.451804] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | board version
[   22.451805] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | hcmd
[   22.451806] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr0
[   22.451807] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr1
[   22.451807] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr2
[   22.451808] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr3
[   22.451809] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr4
[   22.451810] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | last cmd Id
[   22.451811] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | wait_event
[   22.451812] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | l2p_control
[   22.451812] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | l2p_duration
[   22.451813] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | l2p_mhvalid
[   22.451814] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | l2p_addr_match
[   22.451815] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | lmpm_pmg_sel
[   22.451816] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | timestamp
[   22.451817] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | flow_handler
[   22.451899] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
[   22.451900] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: Transport status: 0x00000042, valid: 7
[   22.451901] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x201013F2 | ADVANCED_SYSASSERT
[   22.451902] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | umac branchlink1
[   22.451903] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x8045DFC6 | umac branchlink2
[   22.451904] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | umac interruptlink1
[   22.451905] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | umac interruptlink2
[   22.451906] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x0000000C | umac data1
[   22.451907] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00040000 | umac data2
[   22.451908] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0xDEADBEEF | umac data3
[   22.451909] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000042 | umac major
[   22.451909] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0xF1C864E0 | umac minor
[   22.451910] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00012019 | frame pointer
[   22.451911] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0xC0887F34 | stack pointer
[   22.451912] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | last host cmd
[   22.451913] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr status reg
[   22.451970] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: IML/ROM dump:
[   22.451970] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000B03 | IML/ROM error/state
[   22.451981] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x000075A2 | IML/ROM data1
[   22.451992] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000080 | IML/ROM WFPM_AUTH_KEY_0
[   22.451998] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: Fseq Registers:
[   22.452002] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x60000100 | FSEQ_ERROR_CODE
[   22.452009] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00440005 | FSEQ_TOP_INIT_VERSION
[   22.452016] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00080009 | FSEQ_CNVIO_INIT_VERSION
[   22.452022] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x0000A652 | FSEQ_OTP_VERSION
[   22.452029] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000002 | FSEQ_TOP_CONTENT_VERSION
[   22.452036] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x4552414E | FSEQ_ALIVE_TOKEN
[   22.452043] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00400410 | FSEQ_CNVI_ID
[   22.452050] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00400410 | FSEQ_CNVR_ID
[   22.452057] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00400410 | CNVI_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[   22.452063] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00400410 | CNVR_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[   22.452070] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00009061 | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_DIG_DCDC_VTRIM
[   22.452077] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000061 | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_ACTIVE_VDIG_MIRROR
[   22.452084] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: Failed to start RT ucode: -110
[   22.452086] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: WRT: Collecting data: ini trigger 13 fired (delay=0ms).
[   23.969110] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: Failed to run INIT ucode: -110
[   23.981885] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: retry init count 1
[   23.989288] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6 AX210 160MHz, REV=0x420
[   25.111627] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: SecBoot CPU1 Status: 0x759b, CPU2 Status: 0xb03
[   25.111651] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: UMAC PC: 0x8047f600
[   25.111662] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: LMAC PC: 0x0
[   25.111664] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: WRT: Collecting data: ini trigger 13 fired (delay=0ms).
[   25.111774] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: Loaded firmware version: 66.f1c864e0.0 ty-a0-gf-a0-66.ucode
[   25.111775] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | ADVANCED_SYSASSERT
[   25.111777] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | trm_hw_status0
[   25.111778] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | trm_hw_status1
[   25.111778] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | branchlink2
[   25.111779] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | interruptlink1
[   25.111780] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | interruptlink2
[   25.111781] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | data1
[   25.111782] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | data2
[   25.111783] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | data3
[   25.111783] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | beacon time
[   25.111784] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | tsf low
[   25.111785] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | tsf hi
[   25.111786] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | time gp1
[   25.111787] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | time gp2
[   25.111788] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | uCode revision type
[   25.111789] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | uCode version major
[   25.111790] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | uCode version minor
[   25.111791] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | hw version
[   25.111791] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | board version
[   25.111792] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | hcmd
[   25.111793] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr0
[   25.111794] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr1
[   25.111795] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr2
[   25.111796] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr3
[   25.111796] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr4
[   25.111797] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | last cmd Id
[   25.111798] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | wait_event
[   25.111799] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | l2p_control
[   25.111800] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | l2p_duration
[   25.111800] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | l2p_mhvalid
[   25.111801] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | l2p_addr_match
[   25.111802] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | lmpm_pmg_sel
[   25.111803] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | timestamp
[   25.111804] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | flow_handler
[   25.111875] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
[   25.111876] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: Transport status: 0x00000042, valid: 7
[   25.111878] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x201013F2 | ADVANCED_SYSASSERT
[   25.111879] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | umac branchlink1
[   25.111880] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x8045DFC6 | umac branchlink2
[   25.111881] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | umac interruptlink1
[   25.111882] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | umac interruptlink2
[   25.111882] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x0000000C | umac data1
[   25.111883] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00040000 | umac data2
[   25.111884] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0xDEADBEEF | umac data3
[   25.111885] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000042 | umac major
[   25.111886] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0xF1C864E0 | umac minor
[   25.111887] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x0001209C | frame pointer
[   25.111888] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0xC0887F34 | stack pointer
[   25.111889] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | last host cmd
[   25.111889] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr status reg
[   25.111935] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: IML/ROM dump:
[   25.111936] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000B03 | IML/ROM error/state
[   25.111946] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x0000759B | IML/ROM data1
[   25.111957] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000080 | IML/ROM WFPM_AUTH_KEY_0
[   25.111963] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: Fseq Registers:
[   25.111967] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x60000100 | FSEQ_ERROR_CODE
[   25.111974] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00440005 | FSEQ_TOP_INIT_VERSION
[   25.111981] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00080009 | FSEQ_CNVIO_INIT_VERSION
[   25.111987] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x0000A652 | FSEQ_OTP_VERSION
[   25.111994] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000002 | FSEQ_TOP_CONTENT_VERSION
[   25.112001] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x4552414E | FSEQ_ALIVE_TOKEN
[   25.112008] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00400410 | FSEQ_CNVI_ID
[   25.112015] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00400410 | FSEQ_CNVR_ID
[   25.112022] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00400410 | CNVI_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[   25.112028] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00400410 | CNVR_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[   25.112035] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00009061 | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_DIG_DCDC_VTRIM
[   25.112042] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000061 | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_ACTIVE_VDIG_MIRROR
[   25.112049] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: Failed to start RT ucode: -110
[   25.112051] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: WRT: Collecting data: ini trigger 13 fired (delay=0ms).
[   26.625778] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: Failed to run INIT ucode: -110
[   26.638552] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: retry init count 2
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1232774)

Comment: This does provide an answer.  The answer is to try a full power cycle because the intel wifi firmware appears to be sensitive to fast, soft or otherwise accelerated reboots.

Comment: The comment concerning a ThinkPad does not address my experience on my HP Zbook G2 laptop.   I did full cold boots, not re-boots, not soft boots. The issue concerning timing would indeed be consistent with what I could observe from the scrolling text terminal  messages on the screen during boot; there indeed could have been a specific wait interval between booting sequence operations that was not being obeyed by the previous 22.04 kernels and related code but it did not seem to be a stochastic race condition in that the Linux "wifi" system NEVER worked with the on-board hardware