# No Wi-Fi Adapter found Asus Zenbook flip 14

Tags: networking, drivers, asus

I installed Ubuntu for the first time on my laptop and it does not detect the wifi adapter. Following this [guide](https://www.linuxfordevices.com/tutorials/ubuntu/no-wi-fi-adapter-found-error), I tried to manually install the newest Intel firmware (for Intel® Wi-Fi 6 AX210 160MHz). It did not help. Next, I reinstalled Ubuntu which also changed nothing.

Running the script mentioned in https://askubuntu.com/a/425205/1651284 to collect some information about the wifi gives the following output:

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 20 Nov 2022 19:26 CET +0100

Booted last: 20 Nov 2022 00:00 CET +0100

Script from: 25 Jan 2020 03:34 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu Description: Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS Release: 22.04 Codename: jammy

##### kernel ############################

Linux 5.15.0-53-generic #59-Ubuntu SMP Mon Oct 17 18:53:30 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=7

##### desktop ###########################

Ubuntu

##### lspci #############################

02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 8265 / 8275 [8086:24fd] (rev 78)  Subsystem: Intel Corporation Wireless 8265 / 8275 [8086:8010]   Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 002 Device 004: ID 0bda:8153 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8153 Gigabit Ethernet Adapter Bus 002 Device 003: ID 05e3:0749 Genesys Logic, Inc. SD Card Reader and Writer Bus 002 Device 002: ID 2109:0817 VIA Labs, Inc. USB3.0 Hub              Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub Bus 001 Device 004: ID 8087:0a2b Intel Corp. Bluetooth wireless interface Bus 001 Device 003: ID 13d3:56a2 IMC Networks USB2.0 HD UVC WebCam Bus 001 Device 007: ID 2109:8817 VIA Labs, Inc. USB Billboard Device    Bus 001 Device 005: ID 2109:2817 VIA Labs, Inc. USB2.0 Hub              Bus 001 Device 002: ID 046d:c52e Logitech, Inc. MK260 Wireless Combo Receiver Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

0: hci0: Bluetooth  Soft blocked: no    Hard blocked: no

##### secure boot #######################

SecureBoot enabled

##### lsmod #############################

iwlmvm                569344  0 mac80211             1249280  1 iwlmvm asus_nb_wmi            28672  0 libarc4                16384  1 mac80211 wmi_bmof               16384  0 iwlwifi               450560  1 iwlmvm mxm_wmi                16384  1 nouveau cfg80211              974848  3 iwlmvm,iwlwifi,mac80211 asus_wmi               45056  2 asus_nb_wmi,mfd_aaeon sparse_keymap          16384  1 asus_wmi platform_profile       16384  1 asus_wmi wmi                    32768  5 asus_wmi,wmi_bmof,mfd_aaeon,mxm_wmi,nouveau video                  61440  3 asus_wmi,i915,nouveau

##### interfaces ########################

##### ifconfig ##########################

1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback <MAC address> brd <MAC address>
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever 2: enx<IF from MAC [IF1]>: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether <MAC 'enx<IF from MAC [IF1]>' [IF1]> brd <MAC address>
    inet 192.168.8.128/24 brd 192.168.8.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute enx<IF from MAC [IF1]>
       valid_lft 86148sec preferred_lft 86148sec
    inet6 fdfc:ab90:9176:fe00:d474:d0c8:f2ed:1200/64 scope global temporary dynamic 
       valid_lft 7086sec preferred_lft 3486sec
    inet6 fdfc:ab90:9176:fe00:4488:568:ff11:45fe/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr noprefixroute 
       valid_lft 7086sec preferred_lft 3486sec
    inet6 fe80::1730:f677:385b:779f/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

##### iwconfig ##########################

lo        no wireless extensions.

enx<IF from MAC [IF1]>  no wireless extensions.

##### route #############################

default via 192.168.8.1 dev enx<IF from MAC [IF1]> proto dhcp metric 100 
169.254.0.0/16 dev enx<IF from MAC [IF1]> scope link metric 1000 
192.168.8.0/24 dev enx<IF from MAC [IF1]> proto kernel scope link src 192.168.8.128 metric 100 

##### resolv.conf #######################

[777 root '/etc/resolv.conf' -> '../run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf']

nameserver 127.0.0.53 options edns0 trust-ad search .

##### network managers ##################

Installed:

    NetworkManager

Running:

root         589       1  0 19:20 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

##### NetworkManager info ###############

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         enx<IF from MAC [IF1]> GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet GENERAL.NM-TYPE:      NMDeviceEthernet GENERAL.DBUS-PATH:                      /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/2 GENERAL.VENDOR:              Realtek Semiconductor Corp. GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        RTL8153 Gigabit Ethernet Adapter GENERAL.DRIVER:                       r8152 GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 v1.12.13 GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               rtl8153a-4 v2 02/07/20 GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'enx<IF from MAC [IF1]>' [IF1]> GENERAL.MTU:                            1500 GENERAL.STATE:     100 (connected) GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given) GENERAL.IP4-CONNECTIVITY:               4 (full) GENERAL.IP6-CONNECTIVITY:               3 (limited) GENERAL.UDI:       /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-3/2-3.3/2-3.3:1.0/net/enx<IF from MAC [IF1]> GENERAL.PATH:                           pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:3.3:1.0 GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       enx<IF from MAC [IF1]> GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:       yes GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:      
-- GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     Wired connection 1 GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       6b9bf7d4-3362-3661-aa33-0722e9625780 GENERAL.CON-PATH:                 /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/1 GENERAL.METERED:    no (guessed) CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     1000 Mb/s CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no CAPABILITIES.SRIOV:         no INTERFACE-FLAGS.UP:                     yes INTERFACE-FLAGS.LOWER-UP:               yes INTERFACE-FLAGS.CARRIER:   yes INTERFACE-FLAGS.PROMISC:                no WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               on IP4.ADDRESS[1]:            
192.168.8.128/24 IP4.GATEWAY:                            192.168.8.1 IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 192.168.8.0/24, nh =
0.0.0.0, mt = 100 IP4.ROUTE[2]:                           dst = 169.254.0.0/16, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 1000 IP4.ROUTE[3]:                           dst = 0.0.0.0/0, nh = 192.168.8.1, mt = 100 IP4.DNS[1]:               
192.168.8.1 DHCP4.OPTION[1]:                        dhcp_lease_time = 86400 DHCP4.OPTION[2]:                        dhcp_server_identifier =
192.168.8.1 DHCP4.OPTION[3]:                        domain_name_servers = 192.168.8.1 DHCP4.OPTION[4]:                     expiry = 1669054962 DHCP4.OPTION[5]:                        ip_address
= 192.168.8.128 DHCP4.OPTION[6]:                        requested_broadcast_address = 1 DHCP4.OPTION[7]:                       requested_domain_name = 1 DHCP4.OPTION[8]:                        requested_domain_name_servers = 1 DHCP4.OPTION[9]:                     requested_domain_search = 1 DHCP4.OPTION[10]:                       requested_host_name = 1 DHCP4.OPTION[11]:                       requested_interface_mtu = 1 DHCP4.OPTION[12]:                       requested_ms_classless_static_routes = 1 DHCP4.OPTION[13]:             requested_nis_domain = 1 DHCP4.OPTION[14]:                       requested_nis_servers = 1 DHCP4.OPTION[15]:                       requested_ntp_servers = 1 DHCP4.OPTION[16]:                       requested_rfc3442_classless_static_routes = 1 DHCP4.OPTION[17]:        requested_root_path = 1 DHCP4.OPTION[18]:                       requested_routers = 1 DHCP4.OPTION[19]:                       requested_static_routes = 1 DHCP4.OPTION[20]:                       requested_subnet_mask = 1 DHCP4.OPTION[21]:                       requested_time_offset = 1 DHCP4.OPTION[22]:                       requested_wpad = 1 DHCP4.OPTION[23]:                       routers =
192.168.8.1 DHCP4.OPTION[24]:                       subnet_mask = 255.255.255.0 IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         fdfc:ab90:9176:fe00:d474:d0c8:f2ed:1200/64 IP6.ADDRESS[2]:             fdfc:ab90:9176:fe00:4488:568:ff11:45fe/64 IP6.ADDRESS[3]:              fe80::1730:f677:385b:779f/64 IP6.GATEWAY:                           
-- IP6.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = fe80::/64, nh = ::, mt = 1024 IP6.ROUTE[2]:                           dst = fdfc:ab90:9176:fe00::/64, nh = ::, mt = 100 IP6.DNS[1]:                fe80::feab:90ff:fe91:76fe DHCP6.OPTION[1]:                        dhcp6_name_servers = fe80::feab:90ff:fe91:76fe CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/1 CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[1]:   6b9bf7d4-3362-3661-aa33-0722e9625780 | Wired connection 1

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main] NetworkingEnabled=true WirelessEnabled=true WWANEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager config #############

[[/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf]] [connection] wifi.powersave = 3

[[/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf]] [main] plugins=ifupdown,keyfile [ifupdown] managed=false [device] wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-dns-resolved.conf]] [main] dns=systemd-resolved

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-globally-managed-devices.conf]] [keyfile] unmanaged-devices=*,except:type:wifi,except:type:gsm,except:type:cdma

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/20-connectivity-ubuntu.conf]] [connectivity] uri=http://connectivity-check.ubuntu.com./

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/no-mac-addr-change.conf]] [device-31-mac-addr-change] match-device=driver:eagle_sdio,driver:wl wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

##### Netplan config ####################

[/etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml] network:   version: 2   renderer: NetworkManager

##### iw reg get ########################

'iw' is not installed (package "iw").

##### iwlist channels ###################

lo        no frequency information.

enx<IF from MAC [IF1]>  no frequency information.

##### iwlist scan #######################

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

enx<IF from MAC [IF1]>  Interface doesn't support scanning.

##### module infos ######################

[iwlmvm] filename:       /lib/modules/5.15.0-53-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/intel/iwlwifi/mvm/iwlmvm.ko license:        GPL description:    The new Intel(R) wireless AGN driver for Linux depends:        iwlwifi,mac80211,cfg80211 retpoline:  Y intree:         Y name:           iwlmvm vermagic:      
5.15.0-53-generic SMP mod_unload modversions  parm:           init_dbg:set to true to debug an ASSERT in INIT fw (default: false (bool) parm:           power_scheme:power management scheme: 1-active, 2-balanced, 3-low power, default: 2 (int)

[mac80211] filename:       /lib/modules/5.15.0-53-generic/kernel/net/mac80211/mac80211.ko license:        GPL description:    IEEE 802.11 subsystem depends:     cfg80211,libarc4 retpoline:      Y intree:         Y name:           mac80211 vermagic:       5.15.0-53-generic SMP mod_unload modversions  parm:           minstrel_vht_only:Use only VHT rates when VHT is supported by sta. (bool) parm:           max_nullfunc_tries:Maximum nullfunc tx tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int) parm:         max_probe_tries:Maximum probe tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int) parm:           beacon_loss_count:Number of beacon intervals before we decide beacon was lost. (int) parm:           probe_wait_ms:Maximum time(ms) to wait for probe response before disconnecting (reason 4). (int) parm:           ieee80211_default_rc_algo:Default rate control algorithm for mac80211 to use (charp)

[iwlwifi] filename:       /lib/modules/5.15.0-53-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/intel/iwlwifi/iwlwifi.ko license:        GPL description:    Intel(R) Wireless WiFi driver for Linux depends:        cfg80211 retpoline:      Y intree:         Y name:           iwlwifi vermagic:       5.15.0-53-generic SMP mod_unload modversions  parm:           swcrypto:using crypto in software (default 0 [hardware]) (int) parm:           11n_disable:disable 11n functionality, bitmap: 1: full, 2: disable agg TX, 4: disable agg RX, 8 enable agg TX (uint) parm:           amsdu_size:amsdu size 0: 12K for multi Rx queue devices, 2K for AX210 devices, 4K for other devices 1:4K 2:8K 3:12K (16K buffers) 4: 2K (default 0) (int) parm:           fw_restart:restart firmware in case of error (default true) (bool) parm:           nvm_file:NVM file name (charp) parm:           uapsd_disable:disable U-APSD functionality bitmap 1: BSS 2: P2P Client (default: 3) (uint) parm:           enable_ini:Enable debug INI TLV FW debug infrastructure (default: true (bool) parm:           bt_coex_active:enable wifi/bt co-exist (default: enable) (bool) parm:           led_mode:0=system default, 1=On(RF On)/Off(RF Off), 2=blinking, 3=Off (default: 0) (int) parm:    power_save:enable WiFi power management (default: disable) (bool) parm:           power_level:default power save level (range from 1 - 5, default: 1) (int) parm:           disable_11ac:Disable VHT capabilities (default: false) (bool) parm:           remove_when_gone:Remove dev from PCIe bus if it is deemed inaccessible (default: false) (bool) parm:           disable_11ax:Disable HE capabilities (default: false) (bool)

[cfg80211] filename:       /lib/modules/5.15.0-53-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko description:    wireless configuration support license:        GPL depends:         retpoline:      Y intree:         Y name:           cfg80211 vermagic:       5.15.0-53-generic SMP mod_unload modversions  parm:           bss_entries_limit:limit to number of scan BSS entries (per wiphy, default 1000) (int) parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE
802.11 regulatory domain code (charp) parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

##### module parameters #################

[iwlmvm] init_dbg: N power_scheme: 2

[mac80211] beacon_loss_count: 7 ieee80211_default_rc_algo: minstrel_ht max_nullfunc_tries: 2 max_probe_tries: 5 minstrel_vht_only: Y probe_wait_ms: 500

[iwlwifi] 11n_disable: 0 amsdu_size: 0 bt_coex_active: Y disable_11ac: N disable_11ax: N enable_ini: Y fw_restart: Y led_mode: 0 nvm_file: (null) power_level: 0 power_save: N remove_when_gone: N swcrypto: 0 uapsd_disable: 3

[cfg80211] bss_entries_limit: 1000 cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N ieee80211_regdom: 00

##### /etc/modules ######################

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/amd64-microcode-blacklist.conf] blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf] blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf] blacklist evbug blacklist usbmouse blacklist usbkbd blacklist eepro100 blacklist de4x5 blacklist eth1394 blacklist snd_intel8x0m blacklist snd_aw2 blacklist prism54 blacklist bcm43xx blacklist garmin_gps blacklist asus_acpi blacklist snd_pcsp blacklist pcspkr blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf] alias net-pf-3 off alias net-pf-6 off alias net-pf-9 off alias net-pf-11 off alias net-pf-12 off alias net-pf-19 off alias net-pf-21 off alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/intel-microcode-blacklist.conf] blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf] remove iwlwifi \ (/sbin/lsmod | grep -o
-e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \ && /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

##### rc.local ##########################

grep: /etc/rc.local: No such file or directory

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

##### dmesg #############################

########## wireless info END ############
```

As requested the output of `sudo dmesg | grep iwl`:

```
[    3.823236] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    3.834916] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: loaded firmware version 36.ca7b901d.0 8265-36.ucode op_mode iwlmvm
[    3.984518] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 8265, REV=0x230
[    5.362079] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: retry init count 0
[    5.362943] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 8265, REV=0x230
[    6.713204] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: retry init count 1
[    6.713963] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 8265, REV=0x230
[    8.063664] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: retry init count 2
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the result of the terminal command: `sudo dmesg | grep iwl` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: @chili555 Thanks. I added your requested output.

Comment: Is this a dual-boot with Windows? If so, please disable Fast Boot: https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi#about_dual-boot_with_windows_and_fast-boot_enabled

Comment: @chili555 No it is not.

Comment: Please see the answer here about the power button: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1405123/22-04-802-11-wifi-firmware-failure You might also try a live session of Ubuntu 22.10 to see if there is any improvement.

Comment: @chili555 The power button answer worked! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The solution that worked was the one mentioned [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1415218/1651284) and linked to by chili555 in the comments: hold down the power button for 5 seconds to power cycle the laptop.